# Can not ask my webService WCF with windows phone

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, windows-phone-7

I just finish to implement a wcf webservice and add it in my "Windows phone application" . But now when i want use my appplication and ask the web service , i directly got this error :

```
Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.   This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security .
```

I already activate a trace log and got this result :
Please, if someone can help me , it's for my exam TPI in switzerland .
Thank's a lot

[image]
[image]

Here is my client and server web.config

**

### CLIENT WEB.CONFIG (Windows phone app)

**

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="CustomBinding_IService1">
                <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" includeTimestamp="true" />
                <binaryMessageEncoding />
                <httpsTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://sc-pm0037.swisscaution.local/Service1.svc"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="CustomBinding_IService1"
            contract="ArmsWebService.IService1" name="CustomBinding_IService1" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

**

### SERVER WEB.CONFIG (WCF)

**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel"
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing"
                    propagateActivity="true" >
                <listeners>
                    <add name="traceListener"
                        type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                        initializeData= "Sumit.svclog"/>
                </listeners>
            </source>
            <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="xml"/>
                </listeners>
            </source>
            <source name="myUserTraceSource"
                    switchValue="Information, ActivityTracing">
                <listeners>
                    <add name="xml"/>
                </listeners>
            </source>
        </sources>
        <sharedListeners>
            <add name="xml"
                 type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
                 initializeData="Error.svclog" />
        </sharedListeners>

    </system.diagnostics>
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="Forms"></authentication>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
        <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AspNetSqlRoleProvider">
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <remove name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider"/>
                <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ARMSConnectionString" applicationName="ARMS" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
            </providers>
        </roleManager>
        <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" >
            <providers>
                <clear/>
                <add
                    name="SqlProvider"
                    type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
                    connectionStringName="ARMSConnectionString"
                    applicationName="ARMS"
                    minRequiredPasswordLength="4"
                    minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
                    enablePasswordReset="true"
                    requiresUniqueEmail="true"
                    requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
                    passwordFormat="Hashed"/>
            </providers>
        </membership>
    </system.web>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ARMSConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Arms;User Id=ArmsUser;Password=w7rz8w374_3q4oqr;"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.serviceModel >
        <bindings >
            <customBinding >
                <binding name ="SimpleService.Simple.customBinding0"  >
                    <transactionFlow />
                    <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" >
                    </security>
                    <binaryMessageEncoding></binaryMessageEncoding>
                    <!-- Configure https-->
                    <httpsTransport  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"  />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service name="WebServiceArms.Service1">
                <endpoint address="https://sc-pm0037.swisscaution.local/Service1.svc" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SimpleService.Simple.customBinding0"
                  contract="WebServiceArms.IService1" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true "/>
                    <!-- specify how the credentials are verified -->
                    <serviceCredentials>
                        <!-- Use the aspnet membership provider-->
                        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WebServiceArms.CustomUserNameValidator,WebServiceArms"  />
                    </serviceCredentials>
                    <serviceAuthorization roleProviderName="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles" >
                    </serviceAuthorization>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true "/>
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it ! Just install the SSL certificate on my device before open my application.And it's work nice